# Website on Amazon s3 using Javascript jQuery , call a webService not responding. But working Proper on Local Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

***This is CORS origin problem in JQUERY that restrict DOM to create html element. Please Suggest me solution. In safari if I Disable Cross Origin Ristriction in Works Well.***

I have a NodeJs Rest WebService hosted from ec2 responde Json. I use this in a Static Page using Jquery and JavaScript and Deploy on Amazon S3 bucket. But WebService calling not working there but it Works Properly from system folder to Browser. I added bucket policy etc properlly on s3 bucket.

Comment: "not working" means? error please

Comment: From html page I call main.js file function . In js I use function 
$.ajax({});

Comment: Thanks Mukesh https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/loopanimation/index.html

Comment: `main.js` tries to call http://ec2-35-154-68-165.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/videoCardInfo and this link is not working. It shows connection refused.

Comment: This Rest url responds but on Client side this Error ** XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ec2-35-154-68-165.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/videoCardInfo. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://loopanimation.s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com' is therefore not allowed access. ** deny creation of DOM element in html page. This is CORS Origin Problem in Jquery. Suggest me solution.

Comment: You have to enable it or white list this domain on `server` side.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingBucketPermissions.html at "Add a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) configuration" section.